# How can I position a connecting rod multiple times between two cylinders of different distances?

Tags: modeling

Modelling beginner here.

I want to connect two cylinders to a connecting rod - and this I want to do often.

[image]

So how can I do this simple and quick? The cylinders don't have the same distance. So yes, the connecting rod has to be lengthen as well.

I know about <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> → move cursor to selected and move selected to cursor, but I don't know a quick efficient way to do that.

In this image you can see some "ready" connecting rods (the lower two) and a "not" fit one to the right cylinder.

[image]

Comment: do you mean that what you want to do is what you show in your picture? Yes Shift S is the way to go, select the rods, in Edit mode select 2 opposite circles then Shift S > Cursor to Selected?

Comment: yes, but then i have only positioned one end....how to i rotate and lengthen that it fits to second cylinder?

Comment: could you please show what would be the final object?

Comment: i updated my question - just notice: the rods have different length....

Comment: so you're looking for something that will automatize the length, something like that? I guess you need to do it manually

Comment: actually i am looking for both, how to position and align both ends right and then kind of shorten it, yeah. I am aware of doing manually is needed, but i think my way is a bit complicated...i cut with knife and did bridge edge loops with the end. I hoped there would be some cool solution. Maybe i should work with just "one" end, position that two times and then use track to constraint to the other end...might be the quickest way...

Answer (score 7):

Is this a possibility?

[image]

.. constructing the connecting rods *to* the cylinders..

[image]

Comment: +1....now i learnt "looped pairs" ;) didn't know that, thanks for that hint!!

Comment: @Chris  I've never worked out exactly how Bridge Edge Loops decides what goes with what.. but it seems practical, whenever I've used it.

Comment: me neither...i just try until it fits...and that's how i work 98% with Blender ;)

Comment: the problem with your solution is that i have to select exactly that faces manually so that the connection is looking perfect....so that's still pretty tedious :(

Comment: maybe i should change my question to...how can i connect two cylinders on tangent easily... ;)

Comment: @Chris My cylinder-pairs were dupes of single  pair-object, with the holes pre-cut. (They could even have been mirrored) If you give the each end an on-axis vertex, you can quickly create an orientation from those vertices when  needed, to move one end with respect to the other, in line. I always have 'Create Orientation' on my Q menu.

Comment: clever!! i like that!! thanks for that additional information